# WPF Stackpanel overlaps other elements

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically what the title says. The stackpanel overlaps the menu and I have no idea why. Here is the XAML.

```
    <Grid>
        <Menu x:Name="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="592"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LOCATIONS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="294"  Width="200" Background="LightGray"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an1C1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because `Grid` is a container. If you add elements as children, they are all going to overlap each other with the last child always on top.

What you need to do is use `Rows` in your `Grid` so that each child element has its own dedicated area.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" Grid.Row="0" Height="25" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="LOCATIONS" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Background="LightGray"/>
</Grid>
```

The above code allows you to remove un-necessary `Heights` and `Alignments`.

You can use a `DockPanel` as well to achieve the same effect.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Menu x:Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="LOCATIONS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Background="LightGray"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define rows or columns for the Grid.

I suggest you read this tutorial:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You are filling your grid with 2 elements at the same time. Instead, you should define two rows in your grid. One row with a height of 20 pixel and the second row filling the rest.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu x:Name="menu" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LOCATIONS" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray"/>
</Grid>
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Grid, highest z-index is applied to element which is last applied, so here as you are declaring stackpanel after menu, it is getting z-index of 1 more than Menu which ha bee give z-index of 0, so better you use Grid.Row or Panel.Z-index more..